# Web Interface or Graphic UI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, web-applications

Hey,
i've a simple question.

Task:
Program a backup system which can be used by server-, or desktop-systems. The backup system should include a graphical configuration and status view. The programming language should be Java.

Question:
Would you use a web interface, which will solve these jobs or would you create a GUI in Swing?

My thoughts:
- The web interface has the advantage that is is accessible from everywhere (server - configuration made easy without any additional software on the client side).
- The GUI has the advantage that it is more responsive than a web interface and will maybe look more professional on a desktop-system than, the web interface version.

Which solution whould you choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The desktop vs. web app discussion usually depends on who would use the application, and from where. If it's always going to be used by the person sitting at their desk (or at the desk of the server), a desktop application is a good choice. If the user may be remote a web application is the way to go.

Another consideration is deployment. Is this going to be deployed on one or two machines, or does it need to be installed / available to 10's, 100's or 1000's of users? Deployment and updates across hundreds of machines can be onerous for desktop applications, but a non-issue with web-based apps.

Generally speaking, you can give a much richer experience with a desktop app. In this case, however, "rich" isn't really a requirement. You're going to have a few buttons, perhaps a window showing a log of some sort, and that's about it. So from a usability perspective you can probably create a compelling UI using either method.

If deployment and a rich UI don't really factor in, pick the one that either a) you know well, so you can do a good job, or b) want to learn assuming you have the time.

Since the actual question you asked was "which would you choose", personally I'd choose a desktop GUI based on the little information provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Bryan is totally right. Choose the solution you prefer, since you are the developer :)

I'd prefer the web solution, because I love to play around with these nice Web 2.0 AJAX/JS things. Also there are at the moment a few new Browser Developments, which will make it possible to use an webapp as desktop app.

Basically, it's really no matter which variation you choose.

Answer (score 1):

I did serious Swing work in the past but I see less and less the incentive to use "fat client" technologies with today's web based UI (Ajax, JQuery, HTML5 and efforts like html5boilerplate.com to make them work on older browsers). The browser is the present and future of rich UI, specially as more software makes the move to the cloud.

Comment: I can't agree with the statement that the browser is the present of a rich UI. Future, maybe, though there's still a long way to go. There's yet to be a web based UI that can compete with, say, Photoshop, Word, Excel, or Emacs. Similar features perhaps, but nothing even close to an equally rich user experience.

Comment: I thought someone would bring up Photoshop or AutoCAD. No of course the browser doesn't cut it for such apps. The same goes for video intensive games but then Swing and Java wouldn't be used to write such apps either. They're also really not typical of the vast majority of business apps like the backup software that the OP wants to build.